# Copy only cells >0

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm a Macro novice - just figured out how to add the developer tab, so sorry if my question is  dumb.  I have a list of items in Column A and quantity in Column B.  I want to copy Columns A and B to Columns D and E, but only if the value in Column B > 0 - and I want them to stack, no blank spaces for the quantity = 0 ones.  I found some code online:

```
Sub copyAboveZero()

    Dim sourceRng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set sourceRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B6:B24")
    i = 6

    For Each cell In sourceRng
        If cell.Value > 0 Then
            cell.Resize(1, 2).Copy Destination:=Range("D" & i)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

The problem is that in this example, the quantity was in the first cell.  This one is copying Columns B and C, and I want it to copy A and B.  What do I need to change?  Also, can you paste special values only?  I don't want the formatting to come with it.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your file or write out what the data looks like? You probably don't need to do this with a macro and it can be accomplished with some advanced excel formulas

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  Can I post a screen shot in this comment field?  It won't seem to paste.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To N
        If Cells(i, "B").Value > 0 Then
            Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "B")).Copy Cells(j, "D")
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**:

This addresses your comments:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    Dim J As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    J = 6
    For i = 6 To N
        If Cells(i, "B").Value > 0 And Cells(i, "B") <> "" Then
            Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "B")).Copy
            Cells(J, "D").PasteSpecial (xlValues)
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope.  My data starts in row 6, and I want it to start displaying in row 6.  I changed j=6, but it's copying stuff in row 3.  Not sure what else I should change.  It's also pasting the formatting.  I just want to paste the values.  Thanks for the help!